# How do exclude specific folders via robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I want to exclude all subfolders named "ajax" in any folder from indexing by search engines.

Examples:

```
.com/a/ajax
.com/b/ajax
.com/c/ajax
```

Is this possible via robots.txt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible if you list out each folder explicitly. There is no wildcard support to accomplish the type of thing you want. The [robots.txt exclusion standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) is a little lacking in this respect.